# How to push to nested data using mongoose with 2 ids?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this Node push function but it works only on 1 level nested objects I need it to drill deeper in to a second id in the DB model any one with such experience ?

```js
// One level functional using one id finds the user and update
    const update = await Budget.findOneAndUpdate(
        { '_id': `${id}` },
        {
            '$push': {
                [`${sliceLeft}`]: location
               
            }
        }, { _id: true, new: true }
    )
// Dysfunctional !! how to implement second id targeting to that nested lvl2 deep object
    let updateDeptArr = await Budget.findOneAndUpdate(
          
          { '_id': `${id}` }, //User id
            {

                '$push': {
                    [`${sliceLeft}.$._id`//Second ID ]: location// Data
                }

            }, { _id: true, new: true }
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `$` operator, the array field must appear as part of the query document. So your query should be something like:

```
let updateDeptArr = await Budget.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 
    '_id': `${id}`,
    [`${sliceLeft}._id`]: YOUR_SECOND_ID
  }, 
  {
    '$push': {
       // Nested array field is dayOutcome refer to OP's comment
       [`${sliceLeft}.$.dayOutcome`]: location
    }
  }...
```

Comment: Thanks but for some reason its not working should i put something behind  [`${sliceLeft}.$`??????]

Comment: Outcome: [{
            dayOutcome: [{
                Name: "",
                Amount: "",
            }],

Comment: So `sliceLeft` value is `Outcome`?

Comment: sliceLeft is Outcome and location is { dayOutcome: { Name: '', Amount: '' } } sry for not expalining dayOutcome is the one with unique ID so there should be many of them later

Comment: If so it will be `[\`${sliceLeft}.$.dayOutcome\`]`

Comment: Working 100% thanks a very good solution for targeting nested objects.